# Use user's icons in a bash script

Tags: gnome, bash, icons, scripts

I am looking for a way to use the icons from the users theme (in gnome) in a bash script.

The solution could be a **environment variable** or a **file** where the path to the users icon set is written.

Eg. of use :

```
notify-send --icon=$MYICONPATH/status/32/info.svg "info"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the GNOME environment, you can get the name of the icon theme with `gconftool-2` (Ubuntu versions < 11.04) or `gsettings` (Ubuntu >= 11.04). Depending on your use case, that might already be enough:

*gconf:*

```
ICON_THEME=$(gconftool-2 -g /desktop/gnome/interface/icon_theme)
MYICONPATH=/usr/share/icons/$ICON_THEME
```

*gsettings:*

```
ICON_THEME=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme)
MYICONPATH=/usr/share/icons/${ICON_THEME:1:-1}
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for! And what if my icons where in /home/user/.icons/ ? Can gconftool find that to?

Comment: @danjjl: No, gconf/gsetting only has the name of the theme -- translating this into the path would need library functions like in Oli's python script. You could of course test for the file existing in `~/.icons` first and then fall back to `/usr/share/icons` if it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it directly from a bash script but I've just written a little Python script that you can use as a utility to help you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# pyicon.py

import gtk, sys

theme = gtk.icon_theme_get_default()
icon =  theme.lookup_icon(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]), ())

if icon: print icon.get_filename()
```

Save that as `pyicon.py` somewhere and (optionally) `chmod +x` it.

Then you can call it, chucking in the icon name and the size, and it'll respond with a path. Example:

```
$ ./pyicon.py evolution 32
/usr/share/icons/Humanity/apps/48/evolution.svg
```

If you'd rather keep everything in one place (certainly understandable for one-off scripts), you can inline the python like so:

```
python -c 'import gtk, sys; theme = gtk.icon_theme_get_default(); icon = theme.lookup_icon(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]), ()); print icon.get_filename() if icon else ""' evolution 32
```

Comment: I knew about this way of doing but I was looking for a bash way of doing it, thank you anyway

Comment: It's a better solution than just munging the paths together and hoping it works. With this it finds the nearest possible icon (it'll fall back) at the closest available size.